# How can you fire ComponentListener programatically?

Tags: java, swing, events, user-interface, componentlistener

Is there any way we can fire a `ComponentListener` programatically? For an example, have a look at the below code snap.

```
    private class DisplayAllRevenue extends ComponentAdapter
         {
             @Override
             public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e)
             {
                }
    }

allRevenueJScrollPane.addComponentListener(new DisplayAllRevenue());
```

I have created a `ComponentListener` and attached it into a `JScrollPane`. Now I need to fire this manually using my own code too. How can I do it? I need to fire this code once `JComboBox` event has occured. That means, user selects year or something and this code is then fired... There are lot of `ComponentListeners` I need to fire based on this. These are all heavy database calls which will feed data into different screens, therefore, I am not gonna use the entire set of code inside `ItemStateChanged`

Comment: Define a method processComponentShown() and call it from the listener and directly where necessary.

Comment: @StanislavL: I didn't get you... You mean move the code inside the `ComponentShown` into a method? I am seeking for a direct way..

Comment: Your question sounds like it may in fact be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask "how do I fix this code" when the real solution is to use a different approach entirely.  Better perhaps would be that you tell us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Yeah maybe. I wanted to make sure there is no other way, before I move the code inside `ComponentShown` into separate methods..

Comment: A little more detail on the overall problem would help greatly.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: I need to fire this code once `JComboBox` event has occured. That means, user selects year or something from the drop down and this code is then fired...There are lot of `ComponentListeners` I need to fire based on this. These are all heavy database calls which will feed data into different screens, therefore, I am not gonna use the entire set of code inside `ItemStateChanged`

Comment: Then your listener code should be attached to the combo box, such as an ActionListener or an ItemListener. It makes little sense to add your listener to a property that won't normally fire in this situation. Otherwise you're setting yourself up for some very brittle easy to break code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state:

> I have created a ComponentListener and attached it into a JScrollPane. Now I need to fire this manually using my own code too. How can I do it? I need to fire this code once JComboBox event has occured. That means, user selects year or something and this code is then fired...

The standard way to respond to JComboBox selection events is to use an ItemListener or perhaps an ActionListener.

> There are lot of ComponentListeners I need to fire based on this. These are all heavy database calls which will feed data into different screens, therefore, I am not gonna use the entire set of code inside ItemStateChanged

I don't see anything in this statement above that would recommend to me to create a kludge like trying to artificially fire a ComponentListener. If you have stronger reasons for this, you'll have to tell us, otherwise the canonical answer is not to do this but rather to use the standard listeners as I mentioned above.

Assuming that your program's structure roughly approximates an MVC design, note that your combobox selection can trigger your Control class to change the Model, and the Model change can be significant or can have significant effect on multiple components of your view, components that themselves are listening to the model's state, and I think that this is really what you want to do.

---

**Edit**
You state:

> The reason why I am trying to fire this manually is this. I have JTabbedPane. There are 5 tabs. In every tab, there is a table,which takes its data from the database. The SQL Queries I use to feed the data into tables are extremely heavy, some even join 5-6 tables together. That is why I can't fire the all 5 SQL Queries (for all 5 tables) at once, bcs I am afraid it will fail. If I have a component listener, they will only call the SQL code appropriate to the current displaying table. The SQL code takes parameters. Years. That is why the combobox is there.

Of course it's your program of course, and you can structure it any way that you wish, but if it were mine, I'd gear mine towards an MVC structure mainly so I could more easily debug the constituent parts in isolation and be able to do mocking and such. Sure you could call `getComponentListeners()` on your Comopnent and then fire them if you desire by creating your own ComopnentEvent and then calling each listener's `componentXXX(ComponentEvent cEvt)` method, but I fear that this will result in hard to find bugs and difficulty in testing and upgrading your program. Which component notification method would you decide to fire? What is the program supposed to do when the JVM fires that same method appropriately?

I wonder if you are mixing model and view together. I wonder if better would be to abstract out the model -- the business logic that underpins your whole program and work from there. The model should be notified and thus be aware of table is currently being displayed, and likewise the control will notify it of when the years change. Then the model can request an update from the database, in a background thread of course, and I believe done by the Control. This data will then be sent back to the model. The view will have listeners in the model to be notified of its change, and it will then change the display of your currently displayed table.

If you absolutely must use a GUI-based listener, then use a PropertyChangeListener, since each GUI component has innate support for this listener, and by creating your own bound property, you will have created a listener that shouldn't collide with other GUI behaviors or states.

Comment: The reason why I am trying to fire this manually is this. I have `JTabbedPane`. There are 5 tabs. In every tab, there is a table,which takes its data from the database. The SQL Queries I use to feed the data into tables are extremely heavy, some even join 5-6 tables together. That is why I can't fire the all 5 SQL Queries (for all 5 tables) at once, bcs I am afraid it will fail. If I have a component listener, they will only call the SQL code appropriate to the current displaying table. The SQL code takes parameters. Years. That is why the combobox is there.  (I will post anther comment now)

Comment: Once the year is selected, the SQL query should get the data only applicable to that year. So basically, it is now "Get the data once a year is selected, also make sure to get the data "only" for the currently displayable table". So user can select year from the combobox just "once", and the Tabs in "JTabbedPane" will take care of loading correct data. Imagine the user is selected a year once a Tab is already displayable. The `ComponentListener` is not gonna fire, so we have to "tell" it that year has changed, si refresh the code.

Comment: OK, Thank you. What about moving the "entire" code inside the `ComponentListener`s into another methods, so I can call these methods whenever I want? and, I am using Netbeans GUI builder.

Comment: @Sniper: the database access goes in the Control.

Comment: I mean I do have another DB class and its related interface. What I mean is creating a method like `loadPersonalRevenue()`, `loadBusinessRevenue()` so these will call the database class to get the data. Since these are "other methods" can be called from anywhere I want, from a `ComponentListener` or even an `ItemListener`

Comment: @Sniper: if you must use a GUI-based listener, then use a PropertyChangeListener, since each GUI component has innate support for this listener, and by creating your own bound property, you will have created a listener that shouldn't collide with other GUI behaviors or states. I beg you not to create a kludge out of a GUI listener that already has other purposes. This way lies disaster.